# Merge two sql queries

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

My table `user` has a composite unique index of `subid` and `name`. In order to insert new row into table `user`, I have to make sure that `name` doesn't exist otherwise `subid` has to be increased by 1. I tend to solve the issue with two queries like this.

```
DB.query("SELECT subid FROM user WHERE name='"+name+"' ORDER BY subid DESC LIMIT 1",function(er,rows){
    if(er){
        throw er;
    }
    var row = rows[0];
    var subid = row ? row.subid+1 : 0;
    DB.query("INSERT INTO user(name,subid) VALUES('"+name+"','"+subid+"')",function(er){
        if(er){
            throw er;
        }
    });
});
```

How can I achieve the same result in a single query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it as:

```
  insert into userT 
  select 'bbb', coalesce(max(subid),0)+1 from userT where name = 'bbb';
```

replacing the `'bbb'` with your program's value for `name`.

Here is a fiddle to show it working: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/689db1/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
INSERT INTO user(name,subid)  
SELECT name, 
IF(
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE name='naresh') > 0,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE name='naresh'), 0) 
FROM user
```

Have a good luck